# DbContext keeps throwing "The context cannot be used while the model is being created." error after exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I have a new application I'm developing that is using Entity Framework 6, ODP.NET, Oracle Managed Driver for Entity Framework and an Oracle database.

What I'm seeing is that if an exception is thrown while DbContext is in use, it appears it doesn't dispose either the connection or context correctly.

I'm using a TDD design, my disconnected calls are contained in Repository classes. I'm wrapping my DbContext calls with using statements such as:

```
public class ProductDbRepository : IProductDbRepository
    {
        public ProductDbRepository() { }

        public List<IProduct> GetAll()
        {
            IQueryable<Product> query;
            List<IProduct> list = new List<IProduct>();

            using (var db = new MainContext())
            {
                query = db.Products;

                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    list.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return list;
        } 
    }
```

MainContext:

```
internal class MainContext : DbContext
    {
        internal MainContext() : base("name=OracleDbContext") { }

        public virtual DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(null);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

If an exception is thrown within the using statement such as foreach loop, then subsequent requests to other repositories that use DbConext, I'll see this error:

> The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This
>   exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the
>   OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by
>   multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext
>   and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.",
>   "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",   "StackTrace": "
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()\r\n

To resolve I have to stop debugging and IIS Express. I've never seen this when using EF in past with SQL Server and EF5.

My question is: if there more I should do to make sure the DbContext and connections are closed properly when an exception is throw while using the DbContext?

Comment: `Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(null);` This should be before context created context constructor is good place for it.

Comment: Good tip. Do believe this is related to the exception?